# Controlling TabNavigation inside a Panel

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls

I'm making layout control deriving from Panel in Siverlight. I want to be able to set the tabbing behavior inside my panel. What I need is something like TabNavigation property of the Control class. For example, if I set:

`myCustomPanel.TabNavigation = KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle`

tabbing will move the focus only through the children elements of myCustomPanel. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I know that, this is very late answer, but maybe helpful for researchers.

I have `ParentCustomPanel` and this panel contains many `ChildCustomPanel`.
ChildCustomPanel has many `Controls`(`TextBox`,`CheckBox` etc...).
My problem was I set TabNavigation to `ParentCustomPaneland` it works inside `ParentCustomPanel`.
And now i set `TabNavigation` to `ParentCustomPanel` and it works.

```
ParentCustomPanel.TabNavigation = KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle
```

Thanks!